# Is the function that takes an abelian group to its endomorphism ring a functor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups

Is the function that takes an abelian group to its endomorphism ring a functor from the category of abelian groups to the category of rings (with unity)? I have not been able to find a natural map between abelian group homomorphisms and their endomorphism rings counterpart, so I'm thinking it's not a functor. However I haven't been able to prove this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not only is there not any "natural" or "canonical" way to make it into a functor, but there is actually no functor at all which on objects sends each abelian group to its ring of endomorphisms.  For instance, there exists a homomorphism between any two abelian groups (the zero homomorphism), so to have such a functor there would need to exist a homomorphism between any two endomorphism rings of abelian groups.  This is not true (for instance, consider $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(q)$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q$).

Comment: Great! I was wondering this because I know that the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules is isomorphic to the category of abelian groups, so I was hoping that there would be a nice commutative diagram, $G \to H$, $\mathbb{Z} \to End(G)$, $\mathbb{Z} \to End(H)$, $G \to End(G)$ and $H \to End(H)$ but there's a missing piece between $End(G) \to End(H)$. I was wondering if you can say something about this construction, like if there is a correct way to phrase this in a categorical way.

Comment: How are you getting a map $G\to End(G)$?

Comment: I was thinking the most "canonical" way of doing it was taking $g$ to the function $\varphi_g(a)=ga$, but I'm not really sure about this either.

Comment: That map $\varphi_g$ is not a homomorphism unless $g$ is the identity element.

Comment: Ah well that explains a lot, I got confused with group actions, so yeah this construction can not work. Thanks again!